# Persona 4 Golden Reaper Spawning

Tags: persona-4-golden

What is an efficient method for spawning the reaper? I've been trying to spawn him for hours in Magatsu Inaba with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep opening chests until you hear the rattling chain, the next chest you open will contain the reaper

Comment: Well usually when I listen for it, I open 1 chest and it seemed to be the wrong chest if there are multiple chests on that floor.

Comment: you should have Rise ask for a confirmation if you are about to open the reaper chest